# Not able to send data to Ignite cache through HTTP POST

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-post, http-get, scala.js, ignite

I am trying to put data into Apache Ignite cache using their REST API. So, I used the following links :
To put data into cache :

```
http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=put&key=1&val=b&destId=09f7232d
```

Now, to get this data from cache I used :

```
http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=get&key=1&destId=09f7232d
```

for this, I am getting positive response :

```
{"successStatus":0,"affinityNodeId":"09f7232d-fb4b-4080-b45d-ddd18ce2e32e","sessionToken":"","error":"","response":"b"}
```

But when I tried to send data to Ignite using HTTP POST using XmlHttpRequest through my scalajs application, it is showing "400 Bad Request"

My code for POST is :

```
val xp = new dom.XMLHttpRequest()
val purl="http://localhost:8080/ignite" 
xp.open("POST",purl )
xp.send("cmd=put&key=1&val=a&destId=09f7232d")
```

Can someone please explain why it is showing such behavior ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check response body (`xp.response`) to see if there is any additional information about the error.

Comment: It is possible that you need to set proper `Content-Type` HTTP header: `xp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev thanks for your reply. I've solved my issue regarding the POST method. It is working as expected but I am still struggling with the GET method. The `xg.onload` is not executing at all. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Assign another callback to `xg.onerror` and inspect response.

Comment: Check [Events summary](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#events) section of XMLHttpRequest standard for more information.

Comment: Yes! It is executing `onerror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using below code :

```
val xp = new dom.XMLHttpRequest()
val purl="http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=put&key=1&val=a&destId=09f7232d" 
xp.open("POST",purl )
xp.send("grant_type=client_credentials")
```